# Plural von Arbalest?

Tags: grammatical-number

Ich war bisher der Meinung die Einzahl laute Arbaleste und der Plural Arbalesten. Offenbar heißt es aber [Arbalest](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbalest) . Grimm und Duden bleiben stumm. Wie lautet der Plural?

Comment: Da das Wort im Deutschen so selten verwendet wird, hat es anscheinend keinen gefestigten Plural - ich kann zumindestens keinen finden. Da die Wortherkunft aus dem Lateinischen kongruent mit "balista" ist (was auch dafür spricht, dass der Singular eher "Arbaleste", kongruent zu "Balliste" sein sollte), ist anzunehmen, dass hier auch der Plural im Widerspruch zur Wikipedia kongruent zu "Ballisten" sein sollte - *Arbalesten*

Comment: @tofro https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/please-do-not-answer-a-question-in-a-comment?cb=1

Comment: @miep ist es wirklich unerwünscht, erstmal im comment eine These aufzustellen und (falls keine kanonische Antwort oder ein Gegenbeweis folgt) diese zu einer Antwort zu erweitern? Auf diese Weise werden falsche Vermutungen früh entkräftet, bevor sie sich zu Antworten auswachsen.

Comment: @miep Ich bin sehr dafür, Fragen nicht in Kommentaren zu beantworten. Aber das, was in meinem Kommentar oben steht, ist **keine Antwort**. Eine pure Vermutung wäre eine schlechte solche, vor allem, wenn sie den wenigen aufgefundenen Quellen auch noch widerspricht. Aber der Kommentar kann als Hinweis dienen, wenn jemand vielleicht eine passende Referenz findet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macht man sich die Mühe und sucht im Internet ("*arbaleste arbalest waffen*" bzw. "*arbaleste arbalest museum*") die Museen und Waffenseiten ab, findet man mehrere Varianten: "die Arbaleste", "die Arbalest", "die Arbalst" und "der Arbalest". Die weibliche Variante hat dabei meist Bezug auf den altfranzösischen Ursprung "arbaleste" (später eingedeutscht zu Armbrust).
Da oft nur über ein Exemplar geschrieben wird, wird der Plural auf diesen Seiten sehr selten verwendet - wenn, dann aber immer als "die Arbalesten". Viele Pluralverwendungen finden sich aber häufiger auf Computerspielseiten, die wohl eher nicht zur Klärung des Ursprungs dienen, aber statistisch die Häufigkeit der heutigen Verwendung zeigen. Ich habe keine andere Pluralform als "die Arbalesten" gefunden. Dict.cc listet auch "die Arbalesten". Es erscheint auch sinnvoll, auf Grund der Möglichkeit der Einzahlform "die Arbaleste" als Plural "die Arbalesten" zu wählen, um Verwechslungen auszuschließen.

Beispiele: <sup>[[1]](https://www.franks-woerterbuch.de/all/arbalest),[[2]](https://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/Arbaleste.html), [[3]](http://www.marinero.de/aokisle2/artikel/taktiken/uniqueunits/janitschar.htm), [[4]](https://books.google.de/books?id=3ohtAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT170&lpg=PT170&dq=arbalesten&source=bl&ots=_izMja9-F7&sig=ACfU3U2RnIV7il1HsEeP9a1G6wGCSYw7Vg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi5zdGL_MfhAhViSBUIHb6oBHsQ6AEwBXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=arbalesten&f=false), [[5]](https://books.google.de/books?id=l8IUAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT410&lpg=PT410&dq=arbalesten&source=bl&ots=_1EDglUZwv&sig=ACfU3U2FUIBmZb7CFkUg-_2s0GH81bQuEA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi5zdGL_MfhAhViSBUIHb6oBHsQ6AEwB3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=arbalesten&f=false), [[6]](https://mittelalter.fandom.com/de/wiki/Armbrust), [[7]](https://books.google.de/books?id=yi96CgAAQBAJ&pg=PA221&lpg=PA221&dq=arbalesten%20museum%20waffen&source=bl&ots=ixWsCV-wgp&sig=ACfU3U0WMGbYkdsuDlWJE0hUIeiTKSxziw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiXsvaC_sfhAhWfRBUIHWIxAukQ6AEwCnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=arbalesten%20museum%20waffen&f=false), [[8]](http://deacademic.com/dic.nsf/dewiki/94051), [[9]](http://musiklexikon.ac.at/wboe/1/00000343.pdf)</sup>